# Writing into a String that Defined in the other Function

Tags: python, function

Write a function get_knights_greeting(name, answer='Ni') which returns 'I am of the Knights who say '.
Then write another function get_new_knights_greeting with no input parameters that calls the previous function to return 'I am John of the Knights who say Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!'

I could not find any other answer than below. My question is how can I write John between the given string in get_knights_greeting() function when I am in get_new_knights_greeting() function?

My expected outcome is getting 'I am John of the Knights who say Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!'

How can I get this outcome using the first function nested in the second function?

```
def get_knights_greeting(name, answer='Ni') :
    return  'I am of the Knights who say'


def get_new_knights_greeting():


    return get_knights_greeting('John')+' Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!'
```

The output I got is 'I am of the Knights who say Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!'

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Be a lot easier to help with an example of valid outcome. More so, you're going to need to manipulate the string returned.

Comment: you're passing name to get_knights_greetings that's how.

Comment: I edited the question since it was not clear

Comment: Looking at the code, I would say it produce the expected output, where is the problem? Regarding nesting, Python functions are nestable, you can just move the first function inside the second one.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do something with the argument `answer`?

Comment: @MarcoD.G.The problem is that I am not getting the output I should get. @ usr2564301 I don't think so since it's a default value.

Comment: It's an *argument* to the function (and yes, it has a default value). But you are not *doing* anything with it. Do you understand the purpose of function arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your problem There are two ways to do this first is the following:

```
def get_knights_greeting(name='', answer='Ni') :
    return  'I am {} of the Knights who say'.format(name)

def get_new_knights_greeting():
    return get_knights_greeting('John')+' Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!'
```

Python also supports inner functions so you can also do it like

```
def get_new_knights_greeting():

    def get_knights_greeting(name='', answer='Ni') :
        return  'I am {} of the Knights who say'.format(name)

    return get_knights_greeting('John')+' Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!'


>> I am John of the Knights who say Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!
```

Comment: This is the accepted answer but how can there be a function parameter named `answer` that is not supposed to be used by the function, in other words a parameter that serves no useful purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether you have transcribed the original question accurately. Surely function `get_knights_greeting` is supposed to output its passed parameters. It can do so in several ways:

1. `return 'I am %s of the Knights who say %s' % (name, answer)'`
2. `return 'I am {} of the Knights who say {}'.format(name, answer)`
3. `return 'I am {name} of the Knights who say {answer}'.format(answer=answer, name=name)`
4. `return f'I am {name} of the Knights who say {answer}'` # Python 3 only

And then:

```
def get_new_knights_greeting():
    return get_knights_greeting('John', answer='Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!')
```